# How to execute 3 different controller methods from the same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a `C# ASP.NET MVC` application. In the `Index` view, i have added 3 buttons, when each button is clicked i want to execute 3 different functions from the `Index` controller.

Index View that resides in the Home folder

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

<input  type="submit" value="b1" />

 <input type="submit" value="b2" />
 <input type="submit" value="b3" />

}
```

Home Controller

```
public ActionResult Button1Click()
        {

            return View();
        }

public ActionResult Button3Click()
        {

            return View();
        }

public ActionResult Button2Click()
        {

            return View();
        }
```

When each button is clicked how can i write code to execute the correct controller method ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you handle multiple submit buttons in ASP.NET MVC Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are posting then you can put each button in a separate `form`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Button1Click","Index")) {
    <input  type="submit" value="b1" />
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Button2Click","Index")) {
    <input  type="submit" value="b2" />
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Button3Click","Index")) {
    <input  type="submit" value="b3" />
}
```

If there is no data to post, as shown in your method, and you still want to have all buttons in the same `form` then you can do an ajax post (this does not make sense though but hey I'm basing it on the code you gave in your question), with this though you may want to change your buttons from a submit into a button (`input type="button"`).

```
$("#b1").click(function(){
    $.post('/index/button1click', function() {
    });
});
$("#b2").click(function(){
    $.post('/index/button2click', function() {
    });
});
$("#b3").click(function(){
    $.post('/index/button3click', function() {
    });
});
```

If you want to do a GET instead of a post then just replace `.post` with `.get`.

Comment: When i click `button3` the page gets redirected to `../index/button3click`. And i don't have a view to display, so it ends up complaining that the page is not found. I want it to remain in the Index page it self. How can i do this ?

Comment: What do you intend to do with the buttons, will they be used for a POST or GET request?

Comment: It's a GET request. I want it to remain in the Index page or Redirect to another view. I tried `RedirectTo("Index","Home")` but it doesn't work

Comment: So you want to issue a GET request using your button but then do a redirect? I think it's better if you explain further what you want to do. You can edit your question and explain there, so everybody can see it too and more people can help you out.

Comment: You could do event.PreventDefault as part of the ajax post. http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 3):

In MVC you need to remove the (Asp.Net) idea of linking button clicks to actions. ASP.Net is [event driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) MVC uses the classic [HTTP REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) approach.

So the buttons aren't actions, the buttons `submit` actions. The action that is *submitted* is controlled by your `form`. So your form `POST`s data to the controller, using a [HTTP post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29).

Now it's not clear what your trying to achieve here. You appear to be returning different `view`s from each `action`. So using the REST idea, you should be a `GET`ing not a `POST`ing (your getting HTML). So the simplest idea is to turn your `input`(`submit`) into Anchor tag, i.e. a HTTP GET:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Button1Click")
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to execute different actions on different button within the same form is to distinguish button click by their name:

Example code is:

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyMethod","Controller"))
{

<input  type="submit" value="b1" name="b1" />

 <input type="submit" value="b2" name="b2" />
 <input type="submit" value="b3" name="b3" />

}
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyMethod(string b1, string b2, string b3)
    {
        if (b1 != null)
        {
            return Button1Click();
        }
        else if (b2 != null)
        {
            return Button2Click();
        }
        else
        {
            return Button3Click();
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Button1Click()
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Button3Click()
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Button2Click()
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC doesn't work like Webforms where you have a ButtonClick event.
Do you want to post any values to the controller?

If not, you can use a link that you can style like a button. Use the buildin Html extensions.

```
//For links
@Html.ActionLink("Button1Text","Button1Click")
@Html.ActionLink("Button2Text","Button2Click")
@Html.ActionLink("Button3Text","Button3Click")

//If you need more styling options
<a href="@Html.Action("Button1Click")" class="btn">Button1</a>
<a href="@Html.Action("Button2Click")" class="btn">Button2</a>
<a href="@Html.Action("Button2Click")" class="btn">Button3</a>
```

That way you don't need any javascript or multiple forms in your view. You'll have to add some styling in your CSS files.

Comment: couldn't you just `@Html.ActionLink("Button1Text","Button1Click", new {@class="btn"})`?

Comment: @Liam Indeed, if you just want to add a css class you can use that notation!

Comment: Well technically no, you can add any HTML attributes using that method.